# Use sourceCache in stacktrace.js

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, stacktrace.js

I have trouble understanding the sourceCache option for the stacktrace.js library. Could anyone please explain it to me? How should I form this object? Thanks!

https://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/stacktrace-js